# No such core:xdb

Tags: solr, xdb, xconnect, indexing

I am getting a `no such core:xdb` error when trying to rebuild xdb

```
Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.Failures.SolrResponseException: {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":0},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"No such core: xdb",
    "code":400}}

   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrClient.EnsureSolrSuccessStatusCode(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrClient.<SendGetRequestAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.TaskRetryHelper.<ExecuteTaskWithRetryAsync>d__0`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.TaskRetryHelper.<ExecuteTaskWithRetryAsync>d__0`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrWriter.<SendGetRequestAsyncWithRetries>d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.IndexRebuildHelper.<GetSolrResponseWithRetry>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.IndexRebuildHelper.<SwapCores>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrIndexRebuilder.<CompleteRebuild>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.Rebuild.IndexRebuildFlow.<CompleteRebuild>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.Rebuild.IndexRebuildFlow.<TryToResumeRebuild>d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.Rebuild.IndexRebuildFlow.RebuildStatusWatcher.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<Start>g__RunRebuildFlowCycle|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.Rebuild.TaskExtension.<ExecuteWithInterval>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the connection string for solr core xdb is wrong or the solr core xdb doesn't exist/is not configured correctly.

Can you check if your connection string on xconnect looks like :

```
<add name="solrCore" connectionString="https://yoursolrdomain:port/solr/XP0_xdb" />
```

and you can access the core?

```
https://yoursolrdomain:port/solr/#/XP0_xdb
```